# Julia: setting loop operations only when CartesianIndices reset to starting value (avoid if condition)

Tags: loops, julia

I'm trying to optimize a piece of Julia code.
There is a loop over a range of indices and the key operation inside the loop requires a set of `N` values.
This set of values however, "drags along" - meaning that I can retain `N-1` out of `N` values and just update the last one at each step. If the data was form of rank-1 vector/tuple, that would be easily implemented using a vector of size `N` and `circleshift`ing it at each step.

The problem starts when there are several dimensions, and the `N-1` retained values (which correspond to one line within the M-dimensional space) change each time one of the dimensions resets (goes back to the initial value), meaning we moved to a different line on the M-dimensional data (and for another index).

Here is a schematic example of how this should work:

```
buffer=zeros(N)
for indx ∈ CartesianIndices(selectedrcoordset)
    <Update buffer[1:N-1]=... when any of the selectedrcoordset index is cycled (goes back to first value)>
    buffer[N]=...
    operation!(buffer)
    Base.circshift!(buffer,-one(TI))
end
```

This could be done with an `if` statement at the `<>`, however from what I understand this is something one should avoid if possible.
I was trying to think if there is a smart solution with `InvertedIndices` functionality of `not()`.

Any ideas, suggestions and recommendations are most welcomed!

Edit:
Here's an example code which (I hope) represents what I was trying to ask.
Here I replaced the operation with a simple `sum()`, so that at each location, the adjacent values in direction `idir` are summed (N=3 total).

```
A=rand(6,5,4)
idir=1  # could be anything 1:ndims(A)
step=1

innerdims=ntuple(j-> (1+step):size(A,j).-step, ndims(A))
Outputvar=zeros(size(A).-(2*step))

for indx ∈ CartesianIndices(innerdims)
    Outputvar[Tuple(indx).-step...] = sum( A[ntuple(j -> isequal(j,idir) ? UnitRange(indx[j]-step,indx[j]+step) : indx[j], ndims(A))...] )
end
```

The idea is to hold a buffer for `A` (of length 3 in this case, `three_buffer`) corresponding to `UnitRange(indx[j]-step,indx[j]+step)` and loop over lines in direction `idir` as the most inner loop.
This way, I can keep a buffer and `circshift!(three_buffer,-1)` as the `idir` loop goes, only needing to access the new value at `indx[j]+step`.
Whenever a new "line" is reached (any of the indices resets), the `three_buffer` needs to be reset with the first two values of that line.

Comment: One suggestion/recommendation is to make the code example runnable (perhaps just printing some debugging values). Once the code runs after a simple copy-paste, the response will be much quicker and more focused.

Comment: @DanGetz I had to remove loads of content from the actual code to turn it into an examIe that would actually run. Instead I tried making a new simple example (which I hope reflects the issue correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution, quite succint, but possibly not the most performant (benchmarking would determine this):

```
using Random
import IterTools as Itr

Random.seed!(123)
A = rand(6, 5, 4)

idir = 1
step = 1

interior(ax, width=1) = (:).(first.(ax).+width, last.(ax).-width)

outputvar = mapslices(
  s -> Itr.partition(s, 2*step+1, 1) .|> sum, 
  @view A[ifelse.(1:ndims(A) .== idir, axes(A), interior(axes(A), step))...];
  dims=idir)
```

The `sum` function in the code can be replaced according to the actual application.

Comment: Took me a bit of time to unpack this, but I have!
This is very educational for me, and I appreciate the effort.

I have one question/issue though: in my actual problem there is a second vector/tuple that is needed as another argument in the operation, and the indexing of both are not the same. What would be an easy way to modify the iterator to work using indexing so that I can plug both arguments via indexing?

Comment: @TheWhitestOfFangs As I've said in the comment for the question, give a working code example and answering would be much easier. If needed, make it another question. Also note you can make `s` function in `mapslices` as complicated as you want, and it can use outside variables as well.

Comment: I would like to thank you for the help so far, this has been extremely educational for me. I realized that perhaps I'm chasing the wrong direction (performance-wise)